# sqlite left join with three tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 3 tables

Tenants:_id, Firstname..etc

Tenancy:_id,tenant_id(FK). and others

TenantMeters:_id,tenant_id(FK) and other fields.

I want to construct a query which  returns records  in two  cases:

(1) There is a record for a tenant in both tables(Tenancy and TenantMeters)

(2) There is a record for a tenant  in either Tenancy table or TenantMeters

Any suggestions?

I have tried

```
 SELECT Tenants._id ,TenantMeters.Tenant_id, Tenancy.tenant_id from Tenancy  left join Tenants on Tenants._id=Tenancy.tenant_id  left join TenantMeters on  Tenants._id=TenantMeters .Tenant_id  where TenantMeters.Tenant_id=? Or Tenancy.tenant_id=?
```

But fails in case where i have a record TenantMeters table only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example query is selecting from `Tenancy`, so if the record doesn't exist there then it isn't going to join `TenantMeters`.

The following query will return if there is a tenant in either `Tenancy` or `TenantMeters`:

```
SELECT Tenants._id, TenantMeters.Tenant_id, Tenancy.tenant_id
FROM Tenants
LEFT JOIN TenantMeters ON TenantMeters.Tenant_id = Tenants._id
LEFT JOIN Tenancy ON Tenancy.Tenant_id = Tenants._id;
```